# Why Is API Management Not Triggering Logic App?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I have a logic app that I'm trying to put behind API Management and it's not triggering at all. For testing purposes I created a new logic app with [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-http-endpoint) and I'm running into the same issue.

I'm adding the API by selecting Logic App in the APIM portal, setting a suffix of sandbox and adding the unlimited product. The original url for the logic app is ***https://{baseurl}.logic.azure.com/workflows/{workflow}/triggers/manual/paths/invoke/address/{postalCode}?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig={sig}*** and the url I'm hitting for the api management endpoint is ***https://{apim-name}.azure-api.net/sandbox/manual/paths/invoke/address/{postalCode}***

The result when I hit the logic app directly is `Postal Code: {postalCode}` when I hit the api management endpoint it just returns an empty result with a 200 HTTP Code. I can look at the logic app and see it's not getting triggered.

Has any else run into this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In API Management does it have mocking enabled? In the Design tab under Inbound Processing. I think it also has a message along the top if it is enabled.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger No, the only policies I have are the ones that were created automatically when I imported the logic app, set-method, rewrite-uri and set-header

Comment: Maybe try editing the Backend and selecting the Logic App, maybe the linkage didn't get created properly.

Comment: Tested this in another Azure environment and it worked so I just deleted and recreated the API Managment Service and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you got 202 with empty result, but I test it success. I got the `Postal Code: {postalCode}` after request the APIM endpoint(both request in the APIM test and request it in postman). Here I provide my steps for your reference.

**1.** I create a logic app shown as below:
[image]

**2.** Then I create APIM and configure the logic app url in it.
[image]
[image]

**3.** Click the "Send" button in APIM test, get the response shown as below:
[image]

**4.** When request the APIM request url in postman, it also get result success.
[image]

Hope it helps~